# Server side validation for image upload using MVC5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to validate the image upload in the server side using mvc5. i am using the  angularJS code to upload the image using base64.How do i validate the image. 
this is my code for image upload code in view..

in view

```
 <div>
 <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="!$flow.files.length" data-flow-btn id="Image"        >Select image</span>
 <span class="btn btn-info" ng-show="$flow.files.length" data-flow-btn id="Image" >Change</span>
 <span class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="$flow.files.length" ng-click="$flow.cancel()" >Remove</span>
</div>
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult ValidationControl()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidationControl(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file,ServerValidation model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = model.UserName;
        ViewBag.Email = model.Password ;
    }
    return View();
}
```

in model

```
public class ServerValidation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "password is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image is Required")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Validate what exactly? It there's actually an image being sent?

Comment: need to validate whether the image is uploaded or not.

Comment: simply check if file != null

Comment: Where's your code to handle the uploading process?

Comment: need to check whether the image hits the server or not and the image need to be there after it hits the server. but here the image is uploaded via base64.i am using angularJS flow.js directive to upload the image.